# update conceptual model

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ado.net

I have generated EDM from DB. Later I have removed a column from a DB and once I have updated the model the property in entity for that column is still there. Also I have noticed that even if you will change a column type and refresh the model the Entity in model is not modified.
Is there a way to refresh EDM and apply changes done in DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB changes will be pushed through to the conceptual model in most cases, removing a column is a special case. If the model refresh included this feature, then it might accidentally remove properties that you had added to the conceptual model independently - that would be a bad thing.

To remove an obsolete column, just highlight it in the designer and hit the delete key. You can also remove the column in the edmx file if you can handle editing CSDL.

Comment: Make sure you right-click the model and select Update Model from Database from the context menu. I think that is part of your problem.

Comment: No I have no problem with updating the model. I was just trying to find reason why properties are not removed after refresh when column was removed or why type of property is not updated when column type was modified.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Also, for changing the field type, you can manually delete the old column in the model and it will come back with the right type when you refresh.

Answer (score 0):

When you update the EDM it only updates the database definition not the conceptual model. Probably you get errors afterwards complaining about a mapping failure. You still have a conceptual property that doesn't map to a database property anymore. Remember that the EDM has three parts in it. Only the first time the conceptual model is created based upon the database model and the two are linked together by the mapping model. Afterwards, when updating the EDM, only the database model is refreshed. You have to delete / redefine types of properties by hand.